# How to update value of a cell that have a Hyperlink by Smartsheeet API C# SDK?

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

We have to update value of a smartsheet Cell. This Cell contains Hyperlink to a different sheet. Hyperlink URL is assigned. We want to update this cell value by Smartsheet API C# SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your scenario correctly, a cell in your sheet contains a hyperlink to another Smartsheet sheet ([as described here](https://help.smartsheet.com/articles/518326-creating-hyperlinks-to-sheets-reports-websites)), and you want to update that cell value to be a hyperlink that points to a different sheet in Smartsheet. The following code uses the Smartsheet C# SDK to accomplish that.

```
// Replace the second parameter here with your API Access Token
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN", "replace-this-string-with-your-API-access-token");

SmartsheetClient smartsheet = new SmartsheetBuilder().Build();

// Specify updated cell value (hyperlink to another sheet)
var cellToUpdate = new Cell
{
    ColumnId = 6101753539127172,  // ID of the column that contains the cell you're updating
    Value = "text-value-for-hyperlink",  // text value of hyperlink to display in the cell -- typically set to the target Sheet's name
    Hyperlink = new Hyperlink
    {
        SheetId = 7501762300012420  // ID of the sheet that the hyperlink will point to
    }
};

// Identify row and add updated cell object to it
var rowToUpdate = new Row
{
    Id = 4324392993613700,  // ID of the row that contains the cell you're updating
    Cells = new Cell[] { cellToUpdate }
};

// Issue the 'update row(s)' request
IList<Row> updatedRow = smartsheet.SheetResources.RowResources.UpdateRows(
    3932034054809476,    // ID of the sheet that you're updating
    new Row[] { rowToUpdate }
);
```

Hopefully this is helpful. If I'm not understanding your scenario correctly, please comment on this answer to elaborate further about your scenario.

** **UPDATE - replacing the sheet hyperlink with another type of value** **

Please note, if you want to remove the sheet hyperlink from the cell and replace it with another value, you should specify an empty `Hyperlink` object in the request, as shown in the following code.

```
// Specify updated cell value (just a text value -- i.e., no longer a sheet hyperlink)
var cellToUpdate = new Cell
{
    ColumnId = 6101753539127172,  // ID of the column that contains the cell you're updating
    Value = "new-cell-value",
    Hyperlink = new Hyperlink()
};
```